# VBA Chart Not Including X-Axis

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have the following code that only graphs the y-axis. I don't understand why the x axis is not showing up on the graph. Please help and thanks in advance.

```
Sub NormPerm1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NormPRange As Range
Dim NormPChart As Chart
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set StartCell = Range("AG12")

ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Set NormPChart = Charts.Add

LastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

Set NormPRange = ws.Range("AH12:AH" & LastRow)

With NormPChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=NormPRange
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Normalized Permeate Flow"
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Should this be changed `Set NormPRange = ws.Range("AH12:AH" & LastRow)` to `Set NormPRange = ws.Range("AG12:AH" & LastRow)` ?

Comment: I thought so too, but when I tried that it graphs AG and AH as to separate y axis. When the AG12 to LastRow1 should be the x values and AH12 to LastRow1 the y values.